# How to list only one column of the result Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Imagine the scenario,

I have a table Day_fee(date(Date),fee(Integer))

I want to have a list with only the months of the table, for example:

```
Day_fee
date(Date)  fee(Int)
----------|---------
2012/03/27   1
2012/03/26   2
2012/03/25   2
2012/05/01   3
2012/05/02   3
2012/07/01   2
2013/04/01   2
2013/05/01   1
```

The result => a list with 03, 05 and 07 , without repeat the months.

And the other big question:

I would want a hash o list with month and year, for example {"03"=>"2012","04"=>"2013","05"=>"2013", "05"=>"2012", "07"=>"2012"} , without repeat the months, maybe the table can have more years with the same month

Beacuse, after that, i want to show a html table with the months and paginate that.

Thoughts?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**If you are using Postgres DB**

```
# Postgres
DayFee.sum(:fee, :group => "EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)")

=> #<OrderedHash {"3" => 5, "5"=> 6, "7"=> 2}
```

**If you are using MySQL**

```
DayFee.sum(:fee, :group => "MONTH(date)")
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, it looks like you want a different data:

**Postgres**

```
DayFee.count(:fee, :group => "date_trunc('month', date)").
  map{|d, k| Date.parse(d)}.
  inject({}){|h, d| h[d.month]=d.year;h}
```

**MySQL**

```
DayFee.count(:fee, :group => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')").
  map{|d, k| Date.parse(d+"-00 00:00")}.
  inject({}){|h, d| h[d.month]=d.year;h}
```

To get a 2D array

```
DayFee.count(:fee, :group => "date_trunc('month', date)", 
    :order => "date_trunc('month', date) ASC").
  map{|d, k| Date.parse(d)}.
  map{|h, d| [d.month, d.year]}

# [["03", "2012"], ["03", "2013"], ["03", "2014"]]
```

To get hash with collection of  years

```
DayFee.count(:fee, :group => "date_trunc('month', date)").
  map{|d, k| Date.parse(d)}.
  inject({}){|h, d| (h[d.month]||=[]) << d.year;h}

# {"03" => ["2012", "2013", "2014"]}
```

Comment: Thanks! One aditional question, please, what about if i want no the sum, i want this result {"03"=>"2012", "05"=>"2012", "07"=>"2012"} ? {Month=> Year} , im trying but i cant find the solution.

Comment: Yes, the unique Year-Month, something like {"03"=>"2012", "05"=>"2012", "07"=>"2012"} , any idea? thanks for help!

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: What do you do when there is more than one year for a same month?

Comment: If there is more than one year i would want something like this {"03"=>"2012", "03"=>"2013", "03"=>"2014"}, is the process more difficult? Im using mysql. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You cant have a hash with duplicate keys, perhaps you need a 2D array, i.e.  `[["03", "2012"], ["03", "2013"], ["03", "2014"]]`. Let me know.

Comment: the answer would be a 2D array, then is more complicated than thought, i really dont have any idea about generate that, any thoughts? please

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest string for Rails 3.2 is `DayFee.pluck(:date).map(&:month).uniq` but more faster solution depends on the db and for postgres is `DayFee.select("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as month").group(:month).map(&:month)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [GROUP method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) of ActiveRecord then using the [Month() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in mySQL.

```
Day_fee.select("Month(date) as month, sum(fee) as sum_fee)").group("Month(date)")
```

This should return an Day_fee object with the three months and the sum of the fee.

Answer (score 0):

If the DayFee table is small, I would use:

```
DayFee.all.map{ |df| df.date.month }.uniq
```

If the DayFee table is large, use one of the following:

```
# Rails 3.2+
# Never used pluck, but I think it works this way
DayFee.select("MONTH(date) as month").group_by(:month).pluck(:month)

# Rails < 3.2
DayFee.connection.select_values "select MONTH(date) as month from day_fees group by month"
```

Comment: I changed the name from Day_fee to DayFee to be more idiomatic. I recommend you do the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing the dates, not just month names (numbers), you'd need to get the list of all dates:

```
DayFee.select(:date).uniq   ## active record should generate the correct distinct statement to avoid data redundancy
```

than you can find the unique months:

```
DayFee.select(:date).uniq.map{|d| d.gsub(/.+\/(.+)\/.+/, '\1')}.uniq
```